# How do you multiply two arrays with repeated addition in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int a = 4;
int b = 2;
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    result += b;
}

return 0;
}
```

So I understand this is how repeated addition works. My question is how would I apply this to adding 2 arrays?

The arrays I'm trying to add contain 4 elements all 0's and 1's (binary conversion project). The easy answer would be to multiply the two after getting their decimal value and it worked that way but I'm required to use repeated addition via a for loop.

My idea was nesting a for loop inside a for loop like this

```
Nibble ans;

for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    for (int j = 0; j < r.digits[i]; j++) //This part is what I'm not sure about
        ans.digits[i] += r.digits[i];
return ans;
```

This didn't work so can anyone tell me if I'm going in the right direction? Also why would anyone do repeated addition instead of just multiplying?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is how I added the two arrays I'm attempting to multiply with repeated addition.

```
Nibble ans;

for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    ans.digits[i] = digits[i] + r.digits[i];


return ans;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Can you post a sample input and what you expect as the output?

Comment: *adding 2 arrays* -- What does this mean to "add 2 arrays"?  That can mean 10 different things to 5 different persons.

Comment: I'm open to anything I was simply attempting it with the what I've learned.

Comment: @ZeeK If you don't have a clear idea of what it means to "add 2 arrays" in your case, then it's too early for you to be asking a question here. The problem you need to solve right now is with your requirements, not with your code. We can't help you with that.

Comment: So. Are you trying to create a new array where element `i` in the new array is equal to `firstarray[i] * secondarray[i]` and you want to do this by simulating multiplication through addition (like your first code example)?

Comment: @AnonMail i.e. array[0, 1, 1, 0] + array[1, 1, 1, 1]. When I add those 2 together the output should be the decimal conversion of those 2 binary's which in this case would be 6 + 15.

Comment: It's just like adding manually on paper then with carries and whatnot. Just start from the right and keep track of a carry. Just binary instead of base 10. It's the exact same concept. Try a few times on paper to get the idea.

Comment: [ , , , 1], no carry. [ , , 0, 1], carry of 1. [ , 1, 0, 1] carry of 1. [0, 1, 0, 1] carry of 1. You need a fifth bit but you can just do modulo if you want and leave it at [0, 1, 0, 1].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for being so vague. I explained it in an earlier comment I hope what I said makes more sense.

Comment: @MillieSmith I'll give that a try thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I apply this to adding 2 arrays?

Your logic for addition is in the right direction, but still far too simple to work. You need to accommodate for carrying when each place value overflows. You know, like when you add one-digit numbers together to get 2-digit numbers (e.g. 5+5 = 10)? Your code can't do that, and it's a necessary part of both addition and multiplication.

---

Note in your addition code how you have all three components: the result (`ans.digits`), and the two operands: `digits` and `r.digits`:

> ```
> for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
>     ans.digits[i] = digits[i] + r.digits[i];
> ```

---

> ```
> for (int j = 0; j < r.digits[i]; j++) //This part is what I'm not sure about
>     ans.digits[i] += r.digits[i];
> ```
>
> This didn't work so can anyone tell me if I'm going in the right direction?

You've strayed a little too far, as I mentioned earlier; you need to fix your addition code, first, and then you should *reuse that* in your multiplication code. This will be more efficient for you (since you won't have to test two lots of *addition code* which should be the same) and for your computer (since it won't have that duplicate code, unless it decides it'd be optimal to have that duplicate code).

In elementary multiplication, just like addition, we have *three components*. We have two factors and a result: `ans.digits = r.digits * ???`, for example, where `ans.digits` is the result and the factors are `r.digits` and `???`. However, in your code, you only have *one* factor and a result; you've only given your logic *two components*.

You're using `r.digits[i]` both in your controlling loop and your *result addition*, where-as these should use different components. You're basically attempting what seems to be a squaring operation, and though squaring is multiplication, you're not squaring, right? In your question you mention that you're multiplying *two* arrays. You need those *two* arrays to be distinct from your *answer* array. You also need to *correct your addition carrying*.

---

> why would anyone do repeated addition instead of just multiplying?

It's a great way to exercise a students ability to express logic in a programming language, and to revise elementary arithmetic at the same time.

Obviously, it'd be ideal if all students could just bust out code which performs long division by fast fourier transform or exponentiation by squaring but in practice you need to go back to the basics. You'll likely end up performing long division by repeated subtraction, initially, too, before you decide that's *way too slow for your liking* and start experimenting with your own home-brewed FFT.

Here's what my addition code looks like; it's JS and extends beyond binary so you can't really *cheat* with it, but it might give you some food for thought.

```
Array.prototype.inc = function(number)
{ number = [].from_number(number);
  for (var x = 0; x < number.length; x++)
  { var y = x, carry = number[y];
    do
    { if (this.length <= y) this.push(carry & 0xFF);
      else carry += this[y] || 0, this[y++] = carry & 0xFF;
    } while (carry >>= 8);
  }
  return this;
}
```

I use the *result* as though it's also the first operand. This is acceptable for addition, though when you're multiplying you won't want to mutate either of the operands in an addition, as you'll need those operands for the *next* addition.

You'll notice the *carry* variable. I use a little-endian (least significant byte first) representation, so I carry from left-to-right (or rather, lower index to higher index) rather than the conventional right-to-left. Thus, `[0x80].inc([0x80])` results in `[0x00,0x01]` for me, which is counter-intuitive for humans but allows my numbers to grow and shrink in size during conversion or addition, without me having to move digits around. That is nice.

If you want to emulate a representation more familiar with humans who read numbers from left-to-right in order of significance, you'll want to carry from right-to-left, instead. I imagine in the case of my code, that'd mean using `y--` instead of `y++`, though I'm not so interested in entertaining that thought.

Comment: @Zeek You're welcome, and on behalf of the community, well... welcome. When you find an answer helpful, it is recommended that you click on the "up" arrow to the left of the answer, and if it solves your problem directly you should choose it, or another which solves the problem, as your accepted answer by clicking on the "tick". Comments are meant for suggestions of improvement and/or requests for clarification, etc. Please take a few moments to explore the help centre, and check out a few frequently asked questions...